# ArcGIS Server extension crashing after some time

Tags: arcgis-server, arcobjects

I have developed an ArcGIS server object extension.
It works fine the first hour or so no matter how many times I call it.
However if I do some other work and start calling it after a few hours I get the following errors in the log:

```
Creating instance of service 'Australia2D.MapServer'.
Failed to initialize server object 'Australia2D': 0x80004005: Unspecified error.
Failed to construct instance of service 'Australia2D.MapServer'. Unspecified error.
```

I write to the log whenever the soe enters any of my methods and it does not. It crashes somewhere outside my code.

Basically what the soe does it that it serves out subset of rasters from an Enterprise DB. Each time a new raster is requested it is opened and the IRaster is stored in a Dictionary to speed up the next request.

There are no error logs.

I am not using Marshal.ReleaseComObject().
Some of the SOE examples are using this and some are not.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Do you have other SOEs running?  Have you disabled those to test?

Comment: No other SOEs are running.

Comment: I have a question: Which configuration do you have for the map service which enables the SOE? I am talking about pooling, isolation settings and so on.
Probably you can isolate the issue, to be sure where it is coming from.